# Using rsync to delete a single file

Tags: rsync

File foo.txt exists on the remote machine at: /home/user/foo.txt

It doesn't exist on the local machine.

I want to delete foo.txt using rsync.

I do not know (and assume for the purposes of this question that I cannot find out) what other files are in /home/user on either the local or remote machines, so I can't just sync the whole directory.

What **rsync** command can I use to delete foo.txt on the remote machine?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
rsync -rv --delete --include=foo.txt '--exclude=*' /home/user/ user@remote:/home/user/
```

(highly recommend running with `--dry-run` first to test it)  Although it seems like it would be easier to use ssh...

```
ssh user@remote "rm /home/user/foo.txt"
```

Comment: Can't use SSH for this purpose.  (It's a policy thing, not a technical thing. ;))

Comment: Also:

rsync: link_stat "/home/user/foo.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: Apparently since the file doesn't exist locally, we can't specify it as the source file to be transferred.  The only way files get deleted is if you sync a whole directory; any missing remote files get deleted.  I think.

Comment: oops, I made a typo when copying the command in... it was supposed to specify the directory but I put the filename by accident. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Brilliant! That did it. I swear I tried that exact formulation at one point, but I guess not. Thanks :)

Comment: Now, how do we do this for files in subdirectories?

Comment: @ElleMundy That might be a good one to ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

That's a bit trivial, but if, like me, you came to this page looking for a way to delete the content of a directory from remote server using rsync, this is how I did it:

1. Create an empty mock folder:

   `mkdir mock`
2. Sync with it:

   `rsync  -arv --delete --dry-run  ~/mock/ remote_server:~/dir_to_clean/`
3. Remove `--dry-run` from the line above to actually do the thing.

Comment: +1, but add -r to recurse into subdirs. In our colo facility backup servers only allow scp, sftp, and rsync. Had some chunky obsolete sites to remove, rsync did the trick (sftp would have taken days ;-))

Comment: just to sum up recursive-delete-everything command: "rsync -rv --delete --force /empty/ remote:empty-me/"

Comment: If you use "-a", "-r" is implied. "-a" = "-rlptgoD" <See also: http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html>

Answer (score 2):

Just came across the same problem, needed to use `rsync` to delete a remote file, as **only** `rsync` and no other SSH commands were allowed. The [--remove-source-files](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) option (formerly known as [--remove-sender-files](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=commit;h=47c1197534c3247a2669df86fbc36d4094d6ba93)) did exactly that:

```
rsync -avPn --remove-source-files remote:/home/user/foo.txt .
rm foo.txt
```

As always, remove the `-n` option to really execute this.

Comment: Excellent example of thinking out-of-the-box! Using the remote as source instead of destination

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, use `--dry-run` to test prior. `--delete` deletes files on the remote location per the rsync man page.

```sh
rsync -rv --delete user@hostname.local:full/path/to/foo.txt
```

Comment below stating this will list only is incorrect. To list only use `--list-only` and remove `--delete`.

Answer (score 0):

On your remote host, create two directories toDelete et emptyDir. Move your fileToBeDeleted in toDelete, delete the content of toDelete, delete the directories toDelete and EmptyDir.

```
  ssh "$remoteHost" \
                "cd $backupDir && mkdir toDelete emptyDir && \
                sudo rsync -av --remove-source-files ./fileToBeDeleted ./toDelete &&\
                sudo rsync -av --delete  ./emptyDir/ ./toDelete &&\
                rmdir emptyDir toDelete"
```

For this solution to work, your remote user should be able to sudo rsync without password and to connect via ssh.